# while opening directory in windows explorer that contains space in name

Tags: silverlight

I write the code below to open my given path in the windows explorer using Siver Light 5 .net , it is working only in the case when there is no space in the directory name like "MyFolder", but if there is space in the name of  directory it isn't work.
can any body recognize me the solution.

`dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
String path = @"D:\Video 2";
cmd.Run(path,1,true);`

Comment: Did you try putting double quotes (or escaped quotes) around it so the quotes get passed to the COM property?

Answer (score 0):

better late than never (old post)..
For this scenario, you can encaplusate your path using double-quotes:

```
cmd.run('"' + _path + '"');
```